# Ansible Loop Get Next Value

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm currently having some trouble to do a specific task in a loop.
First of all, I need to loop on specific structure:

```
companies:
  - name: Facebook
    company_url: "https://www.facebook.com"
    company_certificate: "Facebook.crt"
    port_type: "AS2"
    create_filematch: "yes"
    filters:
        - name: "ORDERS"
          regex: "ORDER*"
        - name: "INVOICES"
          regex: "INVOICE*"
  - name: Google
    company_url: "https://www.google.com"
    company_certificate: "Google.crt"
    port_type: "AS2"
    create_filematch: "yes"
    filters:
        - name: "ORDERS"
          regex: "ORDER*"
        - name: "INVOICES"
          regex: "INVOICE*"
```

I need to loop on the subelements of "filters". I'm using the following loop:

```
loop: "{{ companies | subelements('filters', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

The problem is that I need to fill two fields in a template: **match** and **else**.
The **match** field should be the current item of the loop. The second field should be the next item.

For example if I have this subelements structure:
subelements:
  sub1: value
  sub2: value
  sub3: value

Then I use a loop on those subelements and the two fields in my template should look like:

```
match_send=sub1
else_send=sub2
```

and then on the next item

```
match_send=sub2
else_send=sub3
```

How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: you talk about template, so you want to be able to use your subelements list as data input for your template?

Comment: Yes, I want to use subelements to fill up my template. The problem is that I know how to fill the template with the current item i'm looping on, but at some point in my template I need to get the value of the next item of the loop.

Comment: Ok, I think you can't do that. If it was one big template to render, then you could, passing the whole list and using loop.nextitem inside the template. But as you use loop, the rendering task receives only one element at a time.

Comment: Yeah that's my fear ^^. The only solution I've found is to had a subelement containing the name of the next subelement. But It's an ugly solution in my opinion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q: *"match and else. The match field should be the current item of the loop. The second field should be the next item."*

A: [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) serve this purpose. For example

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    companies:
      - name: 'Amazon'
        filters:
          - 'filter-A1'
          - 'filter-A2'
          - 'filter-A3'
      - name: 'Facebook'
        filters:
          - 'filter-F1'
          - 'filter-F2'
          - 'filter-F3'
      - name: 'Google'
        filters:
          - 'filter-G1'
          - 'filter-G2'
          - 'filter-G3'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg:
          - "match: {{ item.0.name }} -
                    {{ item.1 }}"
          - "else: {{ ansible_loop.nextitem.0.name|default('last item') }} -
                   {{ ansible_loop.nextitem.1|default('last subitem') }}"
      loop: "{{ companies|subelements('filters', skip_missing=True) }}"
      loop_control:
        extended: true
```

gives

```
    "msg": [
        "match: Amazon - filter-A1", 
        "else: Amazon - filter-A2"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Amazon - filter-A2", 
        "else: Amazon - filter-A3"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Amazon - filter-A3", 
        "else: Facebook - filter-F1"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Facebook - filter-F1", 
        "else: Facebook - filter-F2"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Facebook - filter-F2", 
        "else: Facebook - filter-F3"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Facebook - filter-F3", 
        "else: Google - filter-G1"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Google - filter-G1", 
        "else: Google - filter-G2"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Google - filter-G2", 
        "else: Google - filter-G3"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Google - filter-G3", 
        "else: last item - last subitem"
    ]
```

> Q: *"I want it to behave like this:"*

```
 "msg": [ "match: Facebook - filter-F2",
          "else: Facebook - filter-F3" ]
 "msg": [ "match: Facebook - filter-F3",
          "else: " ]
```

> *"When it gets to the last subitem of Facebook, for example, the value of next_item should be empty."*

A: Try this

```
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
      vars:
        msg: |
          - match: {{ item.0.name }} -  {{ item.1 }}
          {% if item.0.name == ansible_loop.nextitem.0.name|default('last item') %}
          - else: {{ ansible_loop.nextitem.0.name }} -  {{ ansible_loop.nextitem.1 }}
          {% else %}
          - else: ''
          {% endif %}
      loop: "{{ companies|subelements('filters', skip_missing=True) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
        extended: true
```

Eventually, if you want to create a variable with this list try

```
    - set_fact:
        companies1: "{{ companies1|default([]) + [company|from_yaml] }}"
      vars:
        company: |
          [{match: '{{ item.0.name }} - {{ item.1 }}'},
          {%- if item.0.name == ansible_loop.nextitem.0.name|default('last item') %}
          {else: '{{ ansible_loop.nextitem.0.name }} -  {{ ansible_loop.nextitem.1 }}'}]
          {%- else %}
          {else: ''}]
          {% endif %}
      loop: "{{ companies|subelements('filters', skip_missing=True) }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0.name }}"
        extended: true
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ msg.split('\n') }}"
      vars:
        msg: "{{ companies1|to_yaml }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "- - {match: Amazon - filter-A1}", 
        "  - {else: Amazon -  filter-A2}", 
        "- - {match: Amazon - filter-A2}", 
        "  - {else: Amazon -  filter-A3}", 
        "- - {match: Amazon - filter-A3}", 
        "  - {else: ''}", 
        "- - {match: Facebook - filter-F1}", 
        "  - {else: Facebook -  filter-F2}", 
        "- - {match: Facebook - filter-F2}", 
        "  - {else: Facebook -  filter-F3}", 
        "- - {match: Facebook - filter-F3}", 
        "  - {else: ''}", 
        "- - {match: Google - filter-G1}", 
        "  - {else: Google -  filter-G2}", 
        "- - {match: Google - filter-G2}", 
        "  - {else: Google -  filter-G3}", 
        "- - {match: Google - filter-G3}", 
        "  - {else: ''}", 
        ""
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I was looking for. I still have an issue tho, if I get to the last sub item, the next_item won't be empty but it will pick-up the first item of the loop. If you have an idea on how to stop this behavior :)

Comment: Do you want to all subitems behave as filter-Gx do?

Comment: Yeah, but when I get to the last item of my list of sub elements, the ansible_loop.nextitem takes the value of the first item of my list. :(

Comment: Are you able to reproduce my example?

Comment: Yes. I know what happened now. I misunderstood the next_item parameter. I want only the next_item of the selected item. If you take your example, I want it to behave like this : 
    "msg": [
        "match: Facebook - filter-F2", 
        "else: Facebook - filter-F3"
    ]
--
    "msg": [
        "match: Facebook - filter-F3", 
        "else: "
    ]
So when It gets to the last subitem of Facebook for example, the value of next_item should be empty.

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you have any issues open a new question, please.

Comment: perfect that was the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Despite my comments I think I found a solution.
You might be able to use with_together.

I've come up with a working example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
  - list1:
    - a
    - b
    - c
  tasks:
  - name: with_together
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.0 }} - {{ item.1 }}"
    with_together:
      - "{{ list1 }}"
      - "{{ list1[1:] }}"
```

which gives:

```
TASK [with_together] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'a', u'b']) => {
    "msg": "a - b"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'b', u'c']) => {
    "msg": "b - c"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=[u'c', None]) => {
    "msg": "c - "
}
```

I believe you could adapt it for your use case.